# Download Neo4j server version 2.0.4

Tags: neo4j

I could not find the Neo4j server version 2.0.4. The older releases that I could find are listed here https://neo4j.com/download/other-releases/. But the oldest release is 2.3.11. Does anyone know where I can find older versions?

Comment: Exactly @bouteillebleu.

Comment: Chocolatey has versions down to 2.1.*, but I need 2.0.*. Thanks @ChetanVasudevan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download Neo4j Enterprise under it's free AGPL open source license directly from Neo4j's public distribution site if you need any version before 3.3.0.

DO NOT download Neo4j Enterprise 3.3.0+ binaries from this site - because they slipped in a commercial license.

Here are the direct links:

http://dist.neo4j.org/neo4j-enterprise-2.0.4-windows.zip

http://dist.neo4j.org/neo4j-enterprise-2.0.4-unix.tar.gz

Unzip or untar it and start it up.

If you want Neo4j Enterprise open source binaries after 3.3.0 - then you can get them from my company's distribution site we set up for our US federal government agency clients.

You can also compile the packages from source up until 3.3.0 - but they removed the 'packaging instructions' for Neo4j Enterprise in 3.3.0.

Here is a blog post I wrote explaining what changes after Neo4j Enterprise 3.3.0

https://blog.igovsol.com/2017/11/14/Neo4j-330-is-out-but-where-are-the-open-source-enterprise-binaries.html

I would just use those links above for Neo4j's official distribution.

Answer (score 1):

You can download Neo4j 2.0.4 source code from [this link](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/releases/tag/2.0.4) on Neo4j Github Repo, but I strongly recommend you to use the current version of Neo4j database.

### Building instructions of Neo4j 2.0.4 (from REDME.md)

Neo4j is built using [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) version 3.0.x and a recent version of [Java 7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

The Neo4j Browser module is built using [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/). For skipping that part of the build, see below.

- A plain `mvn clean install` will only build the individual jar files.
- Test execution is, of course, part of the build.
- To add execution of integration tests, use: `mvn clean install -DrunITs`
- In case you just want the jars, without compiling the tests, this is for you: `mvn clean install -DminimalBuild`
- To skip building the browser module, use `-DskipBrowser` (note that you might not be able to build the server without it.)
- To build everything, including running all tests, producing documentation and assembling product packages, use `mvn clean install -DfullBuild`
- To build the documentation see the Neo4j manual
- When building on Windows, use `-Dlicensing.skip` to avoid problems related to line endings.
- The license header check can be skipped by appending the following to the command line: `-Dlicense.skip=true`

Comment: Yeah and build the server. I found this earlier and that is the only option left right now. I'll try to figure out whether it is difficult to run neo4j from source.

Comment: @pasemes Why are you trying to use a so older version of Neo4j database?

Comment: Because I have an application that runs on this version. Actually, I just want to query it (the application runs with an embedded database) and I couldn't find a browser that runs on this version either. So, I'm trying to run the server, since I know it has a browser.

Answer (score -1):

You should try using the newest release available in the 2.x family at https://neo4j.com/download/other-releases/

There is not even a TAG for 2.0.4 in the source repository on github.
https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j